# Python generates wrong HMAC SHA256 signature for JSON string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, hash, hmac

I'm using the JSON file from https://filesamples.com/samples/code/json/sample1.json
With this JSON string as input and string `abc123` as secret key, I'm trying to generate a HMAC SHA256 signature using the following python code.

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import json
secret = 'abc123'

# Contents of sample1.json
message = '''{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}'''
# message = json.dumps(message)
hash = hmac.new(secret.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print(hash)
```

I'm expecting `beedda97cf89103141f2e44cbc6241ced093537c499887289b34d5a3ebc90e97` but I'm getting `2383734eba9903278b5e91766fef3413f35c823090d01196ab5c682af19f4c81`. If I read the JSON file directly, I get a signature different from both. But according to my use case, I can't read the JSON file as such. I have to copy paste the contents in the code itself.

I could get the expected result, with this website https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html and this https://tools.chilkat.io/hmac#macResult. I think some formatting/encoding is getting messed up and I can't figure out what it is! Please help.

Comment: The result of  `json.dumps(message)` and your multiline string are different byte arrays, so their digests also differ. We do not know what did you pass to the online site: new lines, spaces,... So it is hard to judge what result is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between your code and the site is in the end-of-line sequence: your code is using LF (`\n`), and the site is using CRLF (`\r\n`).

Try this message:

```
message = '''{\r
    "fruit": "Apple",\r
    "size": "Large",\r
    "color": "Red"\r
}'''
```

and you will get the same result.

Comment: oh my god. yes. this is it. Thank you very much. I was so close I even used json.dumps(message,indent=4,separators=(",\r",": ")) but failed to figure out there's one more \r next to {

Answer (score 1):

It's the fault of a site. It generates wrong hmac

[This](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online) site will give you expected

```
2383734eba9903278b5e91766fef3413f35c823090d01196ab5c682af19f4c81
```

Comment: No its not. The site is correct. I am expecting beedda97cf89103141f2e44cbc6241ced093537c499887289b34d5a3ebc90e97. Python is probably messing up while encoding/decoding

Comment: @ckax i mean the 2nd google listed site gives a correct answer (the same as python does), so...

Comment: The correct signature for the json is beedda97cf89103141f2e44cbc6241ced093537c499887289b34d5a3ebc90e97. Here's another site, that produces this same result https://tools.chilkat.io/hmac#macResult